# ¿Como puedo pasar una cadena de bytes a PDF con Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

Me estoy conectando a una API en la que me devuelve un PDF en formato bytes y quiero saber si hay alguna forma simple de formatearlo en PDF para poderlo descargar.

Mi problema es que me devuelve una cadena de datos en este formato:

```
b'%PDF-1.7 \n%\xe2\xe3\xcf\xd3 \n1 0 obj \n<< \n/Type /Catalog \n/Pages 2 0 R \n/PageMode /UseNone \n/ViewerPreferences << \n/FitWindow true \n/PageLayout /SinglePage \n/NonFullScreenPageMode /UseNone \n>> \n>> \nendobj \n5 0 obj \n<< \n/Length 6427 \n/Filter [ /FlateDecode ] \n>> ... '
```

Lo que he descubierto que eso es un archivo PDF en bytes.

Intento guardarlo en un archivo y almacenarlo en el ordenador pero no me devuelve nada y no me guarda nada.

```
arraybytes = bytearray(sticker.bytesReport)
fichero = open("prueba.txt", "wb")
pdf.write(fichero)
pdf.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supongamos que la variable `resultado` contiene la cadena de bytes que te ha devuelto el servidor, por ejemplo ésta:

```
resultado = b'%PDF-1.1\n%\xc2\xa5\xc2\xb1\xc3\xab\n1 0 obj\n<< /Type /Catalog\n/Pages 2 0 R\n>>\nendobj\n2 0 obj\n<< /Type /Pages\n/Kids [3 0 R]\n/Count 1\n/MediaBox [0 0 300 144]\n>>\nendobj\n3 0 obj\n<<  /Type /Page\n/Parent 2 0 R\n/Resources\n<< /Font\n<< /F1\n<< /Type /Font\n/Subtype /Type1\n/BaseFont /Times-Roman\n>>\n>>\n>>\n/Contents 4 0 R\n>>\nendobj\n4 0 obj\n<< /Length 55 >>\nstream\nBT\n/F1 18 Tf\n0 0 Td\n(Hello World) Tj\nET\nendstream\nendobj\nxref\n0 5\n0000000000 65535 f \n0000000018 00000 n \n0000000077 00000 n \n0000000178 00000 n \n0000000457 00000 n \ntrailer\n<<  /Root 1 0 R\n/Size 5\n>>\nstartxref\n565\n%%EOF\n'
```

Puedes volcarla a un fichero simplemente así:

```
with open("fichero.pdf", "wb") as f:
   f.write(resultado)
```

En el ejemplo que he puesto, el fichero resultante es un pdf válido que al abrirlo mostrará:

[image: PDF resultante]

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Y si después quiero devolverlo como respuesta de un formulario para que directamente se lo descarguen sin guardarlo en el sistema? El pdf para mí no es necesario guardarlo, pero los usuarios necesitan guardarlo e imprimirlo.

Comment: No sé qué framwork estarás usando para programar el servidor, pero de forma general bastaría retornar el string de bytes como respuesta y fijar la cabecera `Content-type: application/pdf`. El navegador que reciba ese contenido sabrá cómo tratarlo (puede que lo muestre directamente en la ventana, o que le dé opción al usuario de guardarlo o abrirlo con una aplicación externa, según qué navegador use y qué plugins tenga instalados)

Comment: Estoy usando Django 1.11. Si puedo pasar la variable directamente suficiente entonces. Estaba mirando un ejemplo y guardaba el archivo y después lo enviaba, por eso preguntaba. Gracias

Comment: Creo que en Django sería `return HttpResponse(resultado,  mimetype='application/pdf')`